# Can functions not have ordered pairs?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]
This is from Halmos's Naive set theory. The way g is defined here is that it is the set of all $x \in X$ that satisfy a certain property. In other words, it's a set of elements of X, it's elements are not ordered pairs and yet they're calling g a 'function' . From what I've read so far, functions are just relations with a special property and the way relations were defined in this book, I see no way how a relation can have elements that are not ordered pairs.

Comment: No, it's not the set of all $x\in X$ that satisfy a property? It's a relation on $X,Y$, i.e., a subset of $X\times Y$. Where does it say otherwise in the paragraph.

Comment: @DonThousand but how? In the third line it says "For each element y of Y, let g(y) be the *set of all elements of x in X* for which f(x) = y" .

Comment: So am I incorrect in assuming that that means $$g(y) = \{x: (x,y) \in f \}$$

Comment: That's defining the pre-image of $y$. That is not the function itself. $f$ is the function, $g(y)$ is a subset of $X$, as it is the pre-image of an element via the mapping of $f$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by f is 'the' function. There are two functions here, g and f. My question is regarding g.

Comment: If you want to think of $g$ as a function, go ahead.  If you want to think of $g$ as a function whose domain is $\text{Range}(f)$, i.e. $\{y\in Y~:~\exists x\in X~(x,y)\in f\}$ and whose codomain is $\mathcal{P}(X)$, that is fine too.  So for instance, with $f:\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z$ given by $n\mapsto n^2$ you would have $g$ is a function $\{n^2~:~n\in\Bbb Z\}\to \mathcal{P}(\Bbb Z)$ given by $y\mapsto \{x~:~x^2=y\}$., i.e. $g=\{(0,\{0\}),(1,\{-1,1\}),(4,\{-2,2\}),(9,\{-3,3\}),\dots\}$

Comment: $g$ is the *function*, i.e. the set of ordered pairs. $g(y)$ is the **value** of the function $g$ for input $y$ and it is the subset of $X$ with all and only those elements of $X$ such that function $f$ maps them into $y$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Why not just Y as the domain? $\varnothing$ is an element of $\mathcal P(X)$

Comment: @DonThousand Because $\varnothing$ is not accepted as equivalence class.

Comment: @DonThousand Arguably, I could have just written $Y$ as the domain since the problem implies that $f$ is surjective by saying "*$f$ ... from $X$ onto $Y$*" but then I'd have needed to be more careful with my example of $f(n)=n^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$g$ is a function with domain $Y$ that is prescribed by: $$y\mapsto\{x\in X\mid f(x)=y\}$$

Observe that $g$ is **not** the set of all $z\in X$ that have a certain property (as you claim).

For every $y\in Y$ it is true that $g(y)$ is the set of all $x\in X$ that have a certain property.

So we are dealing with a function $g$ that sends elements of $Y$ to subsets of $X$.

What we have is:$$g:=\{(y,\{x\in X\mid f(x)=y\})\mid x\in X\}$$Observe that the elements of $g$ are ordered pairs.

---

**edit**:

I would like to remark that also if $f:X\to Y$ is not surjective we can construct on a natural way an equivalence relation $R$ on $X$.

Its equivalence classes are the non-empty [fibres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics)) of function $f$ and the relation $R$ is defined by: $$xRx'\iff f(x)=f(x')$$

Comment: $g$'s domain is $X$, not $Y$?  That sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, I repaired. I overlooked because I am quite accustomed to quotient maps having $X$ as domain in this situation. Doing it this way it must be demanded that $f$ is surjective, but also if that is not the case then $f$ induces an equivalence relation on $X$.